# Elasticsearch Only Searching From Start

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently, Elasticsearch is only searching through the mapped items from the beginning of the string instead of throughout the string.
I have a custom analyzer, as well as a custom edge ngram tokenizer.
I am currently using bool queries from within javascript to search the index.

**Index**

```
{
    "homestead_dev_index": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "elasticprojectnode": {
                "properties": {
                    "archived": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "full_name"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "full_name"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "homestead_dev_index",
                "creation_date": "1535439085947",
                "analysis": {
                    "analyzer": {
                        "full_name": {
                            "filter": [
                                "standard",
                                "lowercase",
                                "asciifolding"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "mytok"
                        }
                    },
                    "tokenizer": {
                        "mytok": {
                            "type": "edge_ngram",
                            "min_gram": "3",
                            "max_gram": "10"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "iCa7qKJVRU-_MA8sCYIAXw",
                "version": {
                    "created": "5060399"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Query Body**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                { "match": { "name": this.searchString } },
                { "match": { "id": this.searchString } }
            ]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "pre_tags": ["<b style='background-color:yellow'>"],
        "post_tags": ["</b>"],
        "fields": {
            "name": {},
            "id": {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Example**

If I have projects with the names "*Road - Area 1*", "*Road - Area 2*" and "*Sub-area 5 - Road*" and the user searches for "*Road*", only "*Road - Area 1*" and "*Road - Area 2*" will display with the word "*Road*" highlighted in yellow.
The code needs to pick up the final project as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have figured it out.
In the original description, I am using the `edge_ngram` tokenizer when I am supposed to be using the `ngram` tokenizer.

Found on: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html#_partial_word_tokenizers

Comment: That's correct, edge-ngram will only tokenize prefixes from the start (or end) of the tokens.